# .htaccess redirect all pages to homepage except few of them

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have a site with only 2 sub pages that i want to keep, i want to redirect all other sub pages to homepage. This is my current htaccess code:

```
# this is to disable varnish caching on my server
Header set Set-Cookie "_asomcnc=1;   max-age=900; path=/;"

RewriteEngine On

# redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect index.html to root
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [NC,R,L]

# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

I tried few examples i found here on stack overflow but i keep getting redirect loops, or my css file and images are not loaded. So lets say i want to load all files from these two folders:

- /css
- /images

And also i want to keep 2 subpages:

- /subpage1.html
- /subpage2.html

Everything else should be redirected to homepage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To exclude pages from being rewritten, you can either use [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) with `%{REQUEST_URI}` or short circuit the rule chain.

To exit early, insert these rules at the beginning

```
RewriteRule ^css - [L]
RewriteRule ^images - [L]
RewriteRule ^subpage1.html$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^subpage2.html$ - [L]
```

And then redirect everything else to the homepage, unless it is already the home page, of course

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^ / [R,L]
```

---

To do the same with `RewriteCond`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subpage1.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subpage2.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^ / [R,L]
```

This redirects to the home page, but only if `REQUEST_URI` is not css and not images and not subpage1.html and not subpage2.html and not already the home page.

---

When everything works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301`. Never test with [`R=301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).